# Inserting a shortcode or php as a parameter into another shortcode Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, web

Is it possible to use php or a shortcode inside an option of a shortcode? Or is there some other way?

for example:

```
[someshortcode option="[anothershortcode] OR <?php echo ''; ?>"]     [/someshortcode]
```

this is what i'd like to do but wordpress won't let me.   Is there a work around?

Comment: Why would you want to do that in the first place. This is really a XY problem

Comment: I'm trying to make a template for my posts that will grab shortcodes from advanced custom fields plugin.  Some of the shortcodes I use need to take a short code or a php echo the_field('some_field') command for a parameter to display the required information.   Thus a user will not have to fiddle in the edtior, simply fill out the fields, publish and the template i've created in the editor fills the fields automatically by grabbing the fields from advanced custom fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not allowed, and is discussed thoroughly [in the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API#Square_Brackets).

> The shortcode parser does not accept square brackets within attributes. Thus the following will fail:

```
[tag attribute="[Some value]"]
```